# Specify headless or GUI from command-line

Tags: vagrant

According to the [documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/configuration.html) it's easy to run a Vagrant VM in GUI mode:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.gui = true
end
```

However, is there a way to do this from the command-line, for example when running `vagrant up`? For example,

```
vagrant up --gui
vagrant up --headless
```

Different users may prefer to boot the UI or not; it doesn't seem like it should be specified in the Vagrantfile that everyone will use!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The GUI option is provider specific (and only very few providers support it), so it doesn't feel right for a top level vagrant command to add a switch for it.

To my experience the most common use cases for GUI are:

- Running a desktop type machine, in which case the setting makes sense in the Vagrantfile
- Debugging a boot etc. issue, when you just want to enable it for a moment

If you anyway have a setup where it's normal to switch the GUI on and off, you can use environment variables. For example something like this in Vagrantfile:

```
# Returns true if `GUI` environment variable is set to a non-empty value.
# Defaults to false
def gui_enabled?
  !ENV.fetch('GUI', '').empty?
end

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |v|
    v.gui = gui_enabled?
  end
end
```

Then on command line on a *nix system:

```
GUI=1 vagrant up
```

And on Windows:

```
set GUI=1
vagrant up
```

Comment: Thanks for that! It does make sense that not all VMs should support both modes, and that this might also be determined by the provider. I'm using Vagrant to compile a game engine, which may run either as a client or a dedicated server. It sounds like two different Vagrantfiles and provisioning setups may be in order in the long run, but I'll definitely use this environment variable trick for now!

Comment: tried reinstalling kernel headers and shit before (luckily) I came across the answer of yours. THIS SHOULD BE ON THE OFFICIAL DOCS (don't mind the caps) xD